# Segmentation Fault C++ Matrix

Tags: c++, pointers

I want make any matrix[n][n+1] become an upper triangular matrix[n][n+1].

I did this code but that causes a segmentation fault.

```
void diagonalizarMatriz(float** Matriz, int n){
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k ++)
        for(int j = n; j >= i; j++)
            Matriz[k][j] = Matriz[k][j] - ((Matriz[k][i] * Matriz[i][j]) / Matriz[i][i]);
}

int main(){
float** Matriz = new float* [3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
    Matriz[i] = new float [4];

//test matrix
Matriz[0][0] = 1;
Matriz[0][1] = 4;
Matriz[0][2] = 52;
Matriz[0][3] = 57;
Matriz[1][0] = -27;
Matriz[1][1] = -110;
Matriz[1][2] = -3;
Matriz[1][3] = -134;
Matriz[2][0] = 22;
Matriz[2][1] = 2;
Matriz[2][2] = 14;
Matriz[2][3] = 38;

diagonalizarMatriz(Matriz, 3);
```

Comment: `for(int j = n; j >= i; j++)`, really ?

Comment: Would you like to change the matrix or just output it with some zeros in the right places without otherwise changing it?

Comment: Do you just need zeros in the lower left, or do you need a mathmatically appropriate change of the matrix which results in a corresponding upper triangular version?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
for(int j = n; j >= i; j++)
```

you start with n at the upper border of the dimensions of your array and the count up,
very soon you therefor access beyond your array, which gets you a segfault if you are lucky.

At a guess you want

```
for(int j = n; j >= i; j--)
```

to count down.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

Assuming your question is about diagonalizing a matrix (as Eugene claims in the comment section):

In addition to what Yunnosch pointed out, diagonalizing a matrix means that the matrix must be a square `n x n`. However, in `main` you're initializing it to be a `3 x 4` matrix.

#### Original code

```
float** Matriz = new float* [3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
  Matriz[i] = new float [4];
```

#### To get rid of the segfault, change the following part in main (set matrix to `3 x 3`):

```
float** Matriz = new float* [3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
  Matriz[i] = new float [3];

//test matrix
Matriz[0][0] = 1;
Matriz[0][1] = 4;
Matriz[0][2] = 52;
Matriz[1][0] = -27;
Matriz[1][1] = -110;
Matriz[1][2] = -3;
Matriz[2][0] = 22;
Matriz[2][1] = 2;
Matriz[2][2] = 14;
```

#### Finally, to get the following matrix (lower-triangular):

```
1 0 0
4 5 0
7 8 9
```

Remove the equal sign from your third nested loop:

```
for(int j = n; j > i; j--)
```

I assume from here you can work your way through this, to make it an `upper-triangular matrix`.

## OLD ANSWER

Try this:

```
int matrix[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int row = 3;
int col = 3;
int i, j; 
for (i = 0; i < row; i++) { 
  for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
    if (i > j) { 
        cout << "0" << " "; 
    } else
        cout << matrix[i][j] << " "; 
  } 
  cout << endl; 
}
```

Will give you this matrix

```
1 2 3
0 5 6
0 0 9
```

Comment: Please do not only state that there are issues, explain them. Also explain your solution. That would help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service.

Comment: I provided a different solution, since you already touched upon some of the issues and gave your solution. @Yunnosch

Comment: Yes it is a different solution. It is still not an explained solution. You have now even removed the last little inkling of an explanation, that you have found more than one issue. That was not what I had in mind when asking for (more) explanation.

Comment: Also I believe that OP might not be satisfied with just zeroing many of the entries in the matrix, because that might not mathmatically be the goal of their efforts... especially seeing that your solution does not change the matrix and just partially replaces its entries by 0 when outputting. Consider using your commenting privilege to ask a corresponding clarification question. Maybe your interpretation of the questions goal is correct.

Comment: and you're making decision and assumptions on behalf of the OP (not clear, not what's needed ...etc). Let's let him/her decide, shall we? @Yunnosch

Comment: @Yunnosch [All questions/answers contain assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presupposition)

Comment: Nice link, I especially like the part "A presupposition must be mutually known or assumed by the speaker and addressee for the utterance to be considered appropriate in context.". It seems to say that if you know your assumptions, then it is better to state them or otherwise make sure that they apply. You seem quite the philosoph or maybe the philologist. I am impressed.

Comment: `diagonalize matrix ` has specific meaning in math. Please don't answer a question that you don't understand.

Comment: @Eugene the OP didn't mention `diagonalizing a matrix`, he/she said `"become an upper triangular matrix"` Also, he/she asked that the matrix is of size `n x n+1`, in math (as you say), that's not the definition of a `diagonalizable matrix` However, the answer is updated.